# SQLAlchemy Unicode Error - Querying Teradata database

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm trying to use Python's SQLAlchemy library to query a Teradata database. I was able to create the engine okay using the following code.

`from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

`td_engine = create_engine('teradata://' + 'usrname' + ':' + 'pswrd' + '@' + 'myOdbcDataSource' + ':22/?charset=UTF8')`

But when I try to use the engine, I get the following error.

> ValueError: character U+590048 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

This error occurs using all the functions that interact with the database that I tried. For example, I get this error when I try to execute the following.

`sqlStr = 'select top 1000 * from myTable;'
result = td_engine.execute(sqlStr)`

As another example, I get the same error when I try to execute the following.

`td_engine.table_names('mySchema')`

The log right before the error indicates a connection to the database using the ODBC driver is being made so I wonder if this has something to do with the way I configured the ODBC driver. Below is my odbc.ini file located at /Library/ODBC/ on my Mac.

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
myodbca       = MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
myodbc        = MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
myOdbcDataSource        = Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20

[myOdbcDataSource]
Driver                = /Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdataodbc_sbu.dylib
DBCName               = myUrl
DefaultDatabase       = myDb
UserName              = usrname
Password              = pswrd
CharacterSet          = UTF8
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this Unicode error and get the SQL Alchemy Teradata engine working? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Uninstalling Teradata's ODBC driver version 16.20 and installing 16.10 did the trick. Link to downloads for both drivers: http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-odbc-driver-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust encoding to UTF8:

```
from os import environ

environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"
```